# ASP.net WebPermission Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, system.web

I have a page which uses System.Net.HttpWebRequest.
The page gave me error as shown here

[ASP.NET WebPermission Security Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245834/asp-net-webpermission-security-exception)

I tried the solution on the page saying that add **trust level=Full"** when i did this now my web.config is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
      <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
        <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>  
<appSettings/>
<connectionStrings/>

<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

  <customErrors mode="Off" />

  <trust level="Full" />

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <clear />
        <add namespace="System" />
        <add namespace="System.Collections" />
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized" />
        <add namespace="System.Configuration" />
        <add namespace="System.Text" />
        <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" />
        <add namespace="System.Linq" />
        <add namespace="System.Xml.Linq" />
        <add namespace="System.Web" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Caching" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Security" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Profile" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>

  <httpHandlers>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
  </httpHandlers>

  <httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4"
              type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
      <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
      <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
    </compiler>
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>

<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <modules>
    <remove name="ScriptModule" />
    <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
    <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
    <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
    <remove name="ScriptResource" />
    <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode"
         type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode"
         type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

Now the error coming is shown on http://gauravbansal7.7hostfree.com/htmlparser/

Server Error in '/'.

Configuration error.

Description: An error occurred while processing a configuration file required to service this request. Check the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. Parser Error Message: You can not use a section registered as allowDefinition = 'MachineToApplication' below the application layer. The error may be due to the presence of a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. Source Error:

Line 30: 
Line 31: 
Line 32: 
 Line 33:
Line 34:

Source File: gauravbansal7 \ HTMLParser \ web.config    Line: 32

Show Additional Configuration Errors:
Version Information:  Version of Microsoft. NET Framework: 2.0.50727.4211; ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.4209

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 Go to IIS > your website >> .Net Trust Levels >> Select Trust Level as Full(internal)
```

restart IIS and check again.

Comment: mine is a free hosting so i donot have this much control or the settings